# Get percentage difference between current bar close and last bar close price in tradingview

Tags: pine-script

I want to find out the difference in percentage between the closing price of the mouse-selected bar and the closing price of the last bar on a TradingView chart using pine-script.

I am using pine-script v5.

Comment: You can't access the bar selected with the mouse in pine script. As a workaround, you can access the time of the rightmost or leftmost bar currently visible on the chart using `chart.right_visible_bar_time` or `chart.left_visible_bar_time`

Comment: Thanks. No wonder I could not find any answer after googling hard for it.

Answer (score 1):

This can be done by using interactive inputs.
See [Pine scripts are now interactive](https://www.tradingview.com/blog/en/pine-scripts-are-now-interactive-27147/) for details.

Below example does what you're asking.

```
//@version=5
indicator('Bar Selection', overlay=true)

myTime = input.time(0,'Start Bar', confirm=true)

var float selected_close = na
var float pct_diff = na
var label myLabel = label.new(na, na, '', style=label.style_label_left)

if time == myTime
    selected_close := close

bgcolor(time == myTime ? color.yellow : na)

if barstate.islast
    pct_diff := (close / selected_close - 1) * 100
    label.set_xy(myLabel, bar_index + 1, close)
    label.set_text(myLabel, str.tostring(pct_diff, format.percent))

plotchar(pct_diff, 'pct_diff', '', location.top)
plotchar(selected_close, 'selected_close', '', location.top)
```